# Good way for declaration of loop variable in pure C (pre C99)?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, c89

As you know in C you can't declare the loop variable in the initialization of the for loop as opposed to C++. What is the proficient/ good style way to declare a loop variable in pure C? Is it better to be global?

```
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; fmla[i] != '\0'; i ++) {
    //do something
  }
```

Comment: This is good and `i` is not global here and it is a different concept altogether

Comment: "you can't declare the loop variable in the initialization of the for loop" -Of course you can unless you're using C89 mode to compile your code

Comment: use `-std=c99` to guarantee c99 mode.  Also, why would you want to use a global for something so insignificant, it'd be a waste of space.

Comment: It's better to use a compiler that is _at least_ C99 compliant. If you can't, then just declare the loop var at the top of the current scope, like any other variable. Anything's better than global

Comment: Don't tell us that C89 is "pure C", this is just antique C. C is defined by an ISO standard and its current version is C11.

Answer (score 5):

In pre-C99 either you declare your control variables in the head of the function as other variables or using an *inner* block :

```
//some code
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; ...; ...) {
  }
}
// some code
```

This avoid conflicts with other control variables and gives you a semantics similar to C99 for loops.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the loop variable in the initialization of the for loop. C99 introduced this feature.

```
for (int i = 0; fmla[i] != '\0'; i ++) {
   //do something
}
```

#### C11: 6.8.5.3 The for statement:

> [...] **If *clause-1* is a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares** is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; [...].

---

> What is the proficient/ good style way to declare a loop variable in pure C? Is it better to be global?

If you want to use the value of `i` outside the for loop then it is better to not declare `i` in initialization of loop otherwise you need an extra variable to keep track the value of `i`.

Answer (score 4):

That's not true any more. Since C99, you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; fmla[i] != '\0'; i ++) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I meant pre-C99 C.

Answer (score 2):

The C99 standard says:

6.8.5.3 The `for` statement

> The statement
>
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
>   behaves as follows:
>
> The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any variables it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.